# Apply a function on a pandas column

Tags: python, function, pandas

I have created the function below which returns a vector based on two input vectors. I have a pandas dataframe with different columns and I would like to apply that function to some columns of my dataframe (one pandas column would be the first vector of my function (nominal), another one the second vector of my function(CPI) and I would assign the result of my function to a new pandas column). How could I do it?

Thank you very much for your help,

Pierre

```
nominal=[10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10]
CPI=[0.02,0.02,0.02,0.02,0.02,0.02,0.02,0.02,0.02,0.02,0.02,0.02]

def nominal_to_real(nominal,CPI):
    real=[]
    product=1
    for i in range(len(nominal)):
        product*=(CPI[i]+1)**(1/12)     
        real.append(nominal[i]/product)
    return real
```

Comment: um, `nominal_to_real(df.nominal, df.CPI)`? But note, your function returns a *list* that has one more element than your input lists... so I'm not sure how you expect this to behave with a data-frame...

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga, I *think* (read *hope*) he's asking how to vectorize this, which is a fair question since there seems to be sum kind of cumproduct feature.

Comment: @Peslier53, what are you looking for as your end  result?

Comment: Give a [**Minimal, Complete, Verifiable** Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) in your question.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Thank you very much! That worked perfectly! My list has indeed on more element than my inputs, my mistake. I just needed to delete real.append(nominal[0]) and everything is perfect.

Comment: @jpp My question was really simple and the answer from juanpa is enough for my need. However, if there is a way to do this calculation in a better way, I am happy to learn how to!

Comment: @Peslier53, I tried but failed. I too would like to know if it can be vectorised. Would you mind if I edit your question accordingly?

Comment: @jpp yes sure go for it! =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`cumprod`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.cumprod.html) for vectorized solution:

```
nominal=[10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10]
CPI=[0.02,0.02,0.02,0.02,0.02,0.02,0.02,0.02,0.02,0.02,0.02,0.02]

def nominal_to_real(nominal,CPI):
    real=[]
    product=1
    for i in range(len(nominal)):
        product*=(CPI[i]+1)**(1/12)     
        real.append(nominal[i]/product)
    return real

a = nominal_to_real(nominal,CPI)
df = pd.DataFrame(np.c_[nominal, CPI, a], columns=['nominal','CPI','real'])
```

---

```
df['real1'] = df['nominal'] / ((df['CPI'] + 1)**(1/12)).cumprod() 
print (df)
    nominal   CPI      real     real1
0      10.0  0.02  9.983511  9.983511
1      10.0  0.02  9.967050  9.967050
2      10.0  0.02  9.950616  9.950616
3      10.0  0.02  9.934209  9.934209
4      10.0  0.02  9.917829  9.917829
5      10.0  0.02  9.901475  9.901475
6      10.0  0.02  9.885149  9.885149
7      10.0  0.02  9.868850  9.868850
8      10.0  0.02  9.852578  9.852578
9      10.0  0.02  9.836332  9.836332
10     10.0  0.02  9.820114  9.820114
11     10.0  0.02  9.803922  9.803922
```